# If an 11 year old missed surooh

Tags: sawm

If an 11-year-old missed surooh does she/he still fast or not?
Cause its their first time fasting the whole month so in surooh, they eat a big meal and its easy for them but now It looks like its complicated for them

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q &A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: If the fast is a due on a person the age doesn't play any role.